# Processing Sketch Using Data from Arduino is Lagging

Tags: arduino, processing, accelerometer, lag, gyroscope

I am using gyroscope/accelerometer sensors (https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13284) with an Arduino to record rotation. I am using a total of eight of these sensors. I am also using a multiplexer to help with the multiple sensors (https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-tca9548a-1-to-8-i2c-multiplexer-breakout/overview). After my Arduino receives the data I am using it in processing to create a 2-D image of all of the rotating sensors.

I am presently running into an issue with significant lag (the animation of the rotation stops, and then restarts multiple times).  I am using Processing for the visual interface and Serial communication to send data from the Arduino (with attached sensors) to the computer that is running Processing.

Presently, my code reads the sensor, and then sends a value with a letter prefix to be later parsed by the Processing code.  For example, if it reads the "sensor's x1 value" it sends "S" followed by the associated x1 value.  On the Processing side, it checks first if the "S" is present, and if so, reads the following value into the appropriate variable for my animation's display.

Attached is the Arduino code (.ino file) and the Processing sketch (.pde file).  In order to speed up the processing of the data, I tried reading a quarter of the data for each frame of animation.  So in the "serialEvent" method, which runs every time data is sent from the Arduino, there are conditionals like "if(frameCount % 4 == 0){ read first quarter of data}", "if(frameCount % 4 == 1){ read second quarter of data}" etc. This didn't work either, but you will see it in the code below.

Anything Helps!

ARDUINO CODE:

```cpp
#include<Wire.h>
#include "Wire.h"
#define TCAADDR 0x70
extern "C" {
  #include "utility/twi.h"  // from Wire library, so we can do bus scanning

  #include <LSM9DS1_Registers.h>
  #include <LSM9DS1_Types.h>
  #include <SparkFunLSM9DS1.h>
  #include <SPI.h>
  LSM9DS1 imu;
  #define LSM9DS1_AG  0x6B // Would be 0x6A if SDO_AG is LOW
  #define PRINT_CALCULATED
}

const int MPU_addr = 104; // I2C address of the MPU-6050
int16_t AcX, AcY, AcZ, Tmp, GyX, GyY, GyZ;

void tcaselect(uint8_t i) {
  if (i > 7) return;

  Wire.beginTransmission(TCAADDR);
  Wire.write(1 << i);
  Wire.endTransmission();
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Wire.begin();

  tcaselect(0);
  setter();

  tcaselect(1);
  setter();

  tcaselect(2);
  setter();

  tcaselect(3);
  setter();

  tcaselect(4);
  setter();

  tcaselect(5);
  setter();

  tcaselect(6);
  setter();

  tcaselect(7);
  setter();

  Serial.println("done");

}
void loop() {

  tcaselect(0);
  looperZero();

  tcaselect(1);
  looperOne();

  tcaselect(2);
  looperTwo();

  tcaselect(3);
  looperThree();

  tcaselect(4);
  looperFour();

  tcaselect(5);
  looperFive();

  tcaselect(6);
  looperSix();

  tcaselect(7);
  looperSeven();

}

void setter() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  imu.settings.device.commInterface = IMU_MODE_I2C;
  imu.settings.device.agAddress = LSM9DS1_AG;
  imu.begin();
}



void looperZero() {
  imu.readAccel();

  Serial.print("A");
  Serial.println(imu.calcAccel(imu.ax), 2);
  //delay(10);
  Serial.print("B");
  Serial.println(imu.calcAccel(imu.ay), 2);
  //delay(10);

  Serial.print("C");
  Serial.println(imu.calcAccel(imu.az), 2);
  //delay(10);

//
//  imu.readGyro(); // Update gyroscope data
//  Serial.print("a");
//  Serial.println(imu.calcGyro(imu.gx)); // Print x-axis rotation in DPS
//  Serial.print("b");
//  Serial.println(imu.calcGyro(imu.gy)); // Print y-axis rotation in DPS
//  Serial.print("c");
//  Serial.println(imu.calcGyro(imu.gz)); // Print z-axis rotation in DPS

}

void looperOne() {
  imu.readAccel();

  Serial.print("D");
  Serial.println(imu.calcAccel(imu.ax), 2);
    //delay(10);

  Serial.print("E");
  Serial.println(imu.calcAccel(imu.ay), 2);
    //delay(10);

  Serial.print("F");
  Serial.println(imu.calcAccel(imu.az), 2);
    //delay(10);


//
//  imu.readGyro(); // Update gyroscope data
//  Serial.print("d");
//  Serial.println(imu.calcGyro(imu.gx)); // Print x-axis rotation in DPS
//  Serial.print("e");
//  Serial.println(imu.calcGyro(imu.gy)); // Print y-axis rotation in DPS
//  Serial.print("f");
//  Serial.println(imu.calcGyro(imu.gz)); // Print z-axis rotation in DPS
}

void looperTwo() {
  imu.readAccel();

  Serial.print("G");
  Serial.println(imu.calcAccel(imu.ax), 2);
  //delay(10);

  Serial.print("H");
  Serial.println(imu.calcAccel(imu.ay), 2);
  //delay(10);

  Serial.print("I");
  Serial.println(imu.calcAccel(imu.az), 2);
  //delay(10);


//  imu.readGyro(); // Update gyroscope data
//  Serial.print("g");
//  Serial.println(imu.calcGyro(imu.gx)); // Print x-axis rotation in DPS
//  Serial.print("h");
//  Serial.println(imu.calcGyro(imu.gy)); // Print y-axis rotation in DPS
//  Serial.print("i");
//  Serial.println(imu.calcGyro(imu.gz)); // Print z-axis rotation in DPS
//  
}

void looperThree() {
  imu.readAccel();

  Serial.print("J");
  Serial.println(imu.calcAccel(imu.ax), 2);
  //delay(10);

  Serial.print("K");
  Serial.println(imu.calcAccel(imu.ay), 2);
  //delay(10);

  Serial.print("L");
  Serial.println(imu.calcAccel(imu.az), 2);
    //delay(10);


//  imu.readGyro(); // Update gyroscope data
//  Serial.print("j");
//  Serial.println(imu.calcGyro(imu.gx)); // Print x-axis rotation in DPS
//  Serial.print("k");
//  Serial.println(imu.calcGyro(imu.gy)); // Print y-axis rotation in DPS
//  Serial.print("l");
//  Serial.println(imu.calcGyro(imu.gz)); // Print z-axis rotation in DPS
//  
}

void looperFour() {
  imu.readAccel();

  Serial.print("M");
  Serial.println(imu.calcAccel(imu.ax), 2);
    //delay(10);

  Serial.print("N");
  Serial.println(imu.calcAccel(imu.ay), 2);
  //delay(10);

  Serial.print("O");
  Serial.println(imu.calcAccel(imu.az), 2);
  //delay(10);

//
//    imu.readGyro(); // Update gyroscope data
//  Serial.print("m");
//  Serial.println(imu.calcGyro(imu.gx)); // Print x-axis rotation in DPS
//  Serial.print("n");
//  Serial.println(imu.calcGyro(imu.gy)); // Print y-axis rotation in DPS
//  Serial.print("o");
//  Serial.println(imu.calcGyro(imu.gz)); // Print z-axis rotation in DPS

}

void looperFive() {
  imu.readAccel();

  Serial.print("P");
  Serial.println(imu.calcAccel(imu.ax), 2);
  //delay(10);

  Serial.print("Q");
  Serial.println(imu.calcAccel(imu.ay), 2);
  //delay(10);

  Serial.print("R");
  Serial.println(imu.calcAccel(imu.az), 2);
  //delay(10);

//
//    imu.readGyro(); // Update gyroscope data
//  Serial.print("p");
//  Serial.println(imu.calcGyro(imu.gx)); // Print x-axis rotation in DPS
//  Serial.print("q");
//  Serial.println(imu.calcGyro(imu.gy)); // Print y-axis rotation in DPS
//  Serial.print("r");
//  Serial.println(imu.calcGyro(imu.gz)); // Print z-axis rotation in DPS

}

void looperSix() {
  imu.readAccel();

  Serial.print("S");
  Serial.println(imu.calcAccel(imu.ax), 2);
  //delay(10);

  Serial.print("T");
  Serial.println(imu.calcAccel(imu.ay), 2);
  //delay(10);

  Serial.print("U");
  Serial.println(imu.calcAccel(imu.az), 2);
  //delay(10);

//
//    imu.readGyro(); // Update gyroscope data
//  Serial.print("s");
//  Serial.println(imu.calcGyro(imu.gx)); // Print x-axis rotation in DPS
//  Serial.print("t");
//  Serial.println(imu.calcGyro(imu.gy)); // Print y-axis rotation in DPS
//  Serial.print("u");
//  Serial.println(imu.calcGyro(imu.gz)); // Print z-axis rotation in DPS

}

void looperSeven() {
  imu.readAccel();

  Serial.print("V");
  Serial.println(imu.calcAccel(imu.ax), 2);
  //delay(10);

  Serial.print("W");
  Serial.println(imu.calcAccel(imu.ay), 2);
  //delay(10);

  Serial.print("X");
  Serial.println(imu.calcAccel(imu.az), 2);
  //delay(10);

//
//    imu.readGyro(); // Update gyroscope data
//  Serial.print("v");
//  Serial.println(imu.calcGyro(imu.gx)); // Print x-axis rotation in DPS
//  Serial.print("w");
//  Serial.println(imu.calcGyro(imu.gy)); // Print y-axis rotation in DPS
//  Serial.print("x");
//  Serial.println(imu.calcGyro(imu.gz)); // Print z-axis rotation in DPS
  delay(50);
}
```

Processing Code serialEvent:

```cpp
void serialEvent(Serial port) { 
  String inData = port.readStringUntil('\n');
  inData = trim(inData);                 // cut off white space (carriage return)
  //println(inData);
  if (frameCount % 4 == 0) {

    if (inData.charAt(0) == 'S') {       //S
      inData = inData.substring(1);     
      rightHipX1 = float(inData);
    }
    if (inData.charAt(0) == 'T') {      //T
      inData = inData.substring(1);    
      rightHipY1 = float(inData);
    }
    if (inData.charAt(0) == 'U') {     
      inData = inData.substring(1);   //U
      rightHipZ1 = float(inData);
    }
    if (inData.charAt(0) == 'V') {       //V
      inData = inData.substring(1);     
      rightHipX2 = float(inData);
    }
    if (inData.charAt(0) == 'W') {       //W
      inData = inData.substring(1);     
      rightHipY2 = float(inData);
    }
    if (inData.charAt(0) == 'X') {        //X
      inData = inData.substring(1);      
      rightHipZ2 = float(inData);
    }
  }
  if (frameCount % 4 == 1)
  {
    if (inData.charAt(0) == 'M') {       
      inData = inData.substring(1);     
      rightLegX1 = float(inData);
    }
    if (inData.charAt(0) == 'N') {      
      inData = inData.substring(1);    
      rightLegY1 = float(inData);
    }
    if (inData.charAt(0) == 'O') {     
      inData = inData.substring(1);   
      rightLegZ1 = float(inData);
    }
    if (inData.charAt(0) == 'P') {       
      inData = inData.substring(1);     
      rightLegX2 = float(inData);
    }
    if (inData.charAt(0) == 'Q') {       
      inData = inData.substring(1);     
      rightLegY2 = float(inData);
    }
    if (inData.charAt(0) == 'R') {        
      inData = inData.substring(1);      
      rightLegZ2 = float(inData);
    }
  }
  if (frameCount % 4 == 2)
  {
    if (inData.charAt(0) == 'D') {       
      inData = inData.substring(1);     
      leftHipX1 = float(inData);
    }
    if (inData.charAt(0) == 'E') {      
      inData = inData.substring(1);    
      leftHipY1 = float(inData);
    }
    if (inData.charAt(0) == 'F') {     
      inData = inData.substring(1);   
      leftHipZ1 = float(inData);
    }
    if (inData.charAt(0) == 'A') {       
      inData = inData.substring(1);     
      leftHipX2 = float(inData);
    }
    if (inData.charAt(0) == 'B') {       
      inData = inData.substring(1);     
      leftHipY2 = float(inData);
    }
    if (inData.charAt(0) == 'C') {        
      inData = inData.substring(1);      
      leftHipZ2 = float(inData);
    }
  }
  if (frameCount % 4 == 3)
  {
    if (inData.charAt(0) == 'G') {       
      inData = inData.substring(1);     
      leftLegX1 = float(inData);
    }
    if (inData.charAt(0) == 'H') {      
      inData = inData.substring(1);    
      leftLegY1 = float(inData);
    }
    if (inData.charAt(0) == 'I') {     
      inData = inData.substring(1);   
      leftLegZ1 = float(inData);
    }
    if (inData.charAt(0) == 'J') {       
      inData = inData.substring(1);     
      leftLegX2 = float(inData);
    }
    if (inData.charAt(0) == 'K') {       
      inData = inData.substring(1);     
      leftLegY2 = float(inData);
    }
    if (inData.charAt(0) == 'L') {        
      inData = inData.substring(1);      
      leftLegZ2 = float(inData);
    }
  }
}
```

Then after importing the data, it is then all using for rotation on visual elements of my processing sketch.

Answer (score 1):

The actual chip of your multiplexer board is a TCA954A. The [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tca9548a.pdf) says the max frequency is 400kHz. Your throughput will depend on
* the packet size in bits (Read/write command, address and data: 2 bytes per axis)
* the number of i2c devices

If you make the calculations, you will probably see that you cannot reach the full potential of you sensors. On top of that, the I2C bus is slower than SPI, because there are control data exchanged. The fastest you can go is a SPI stream with DMA. The full clock is used for data only, and directly written to the MCU memory (an array typically). You can plus several slaves on a single SPI bus, you just need a pin for chip select (CS) for every slave. There is a [nice diagram on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Peripheral_Interface_Bus#Independent_slave_configuration).